# Get unencrypted password from MembershipProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I'd like to get user password unencrypted. How to get this?

```
 public static string GetCurrentUserPassword(string userName)
 {
     MembershipProvider p = (MembershipProvider)Membership.Providers["Default"];
     MembershipUser obj = Membership.GetUser(userName);
    return obj.GetPassword();             
 }  


obj type : [Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Model.User] = User "user1", Id={59d9813c-f88e-4790-9f19-3145ba8347d1}, Provider="Default"

password : "+HmReh/mzvIIuvYsM7+XdEoeQhI="
```

Comment: I cannot think of any good reason to do this. You should never know your users passwords. If you know, a hacker could know if you get compromised.

Comment: @KingCronus, I'd want to write 'Forget Pasword' page. If user forget password want to send e-mail.

Comment: So you are going to send them their password over plaintext email? Bad idea - I would leave any website that did that to me, delete my account and never go back. Why not give them a way to reset it, rather than telling them what it is.

Comment: @baros when the user forgets their password a reset password should be used to protect them from outside attacks. If a users email is hacked then the hacker can use the forgot password link to retrieve the users current password and gain access to any other site where that user has the same password. However if it just returns a new password then that will not be an issue.

Comment: @KingCronus, Yes, I purpose to send with plaintext. how can I create the structure you are referring to?

Comment: @baros - Just create a new random password and send them that. Assuming they answer a secret question correctly or something along those lines.

Comment: @JoeW How retrieve current password using the forgot password link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would you *expect* to be able to get the unencrypted password?

The only think you should be able to do with a stored password is use it to check the validity of the password the user has entered. For one-way hashing (and similar techniques) that involves applying the same transformation to the just-entered password (using the same salt where appropriate), and seeing whether you end up with the same hash.

You should *not* be storing any representation of the password which is reversible. That would mean that if an attacker gained access to your database (and any private keys), they would have access to your user's passwords directly - which is unacceptable, basically. (It wouldn't be so bad if everyone used a different password for each resource they protected, but many people don't.)

Answer (score 4):

If the passwords are configured to be hashed and not encrypted, you can't do this. If you configure the membership provider to used encrypted passwords, then the [GetPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.getpassword.aspx) should do the trick. See [PasswordFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.passwordformat.aspx)

That being said, I certainly can't disagree with Mr. Skeet's answer. You should really be using one-way hashed passwords if at all possible.

For dealing with forgotten password scenarios, take a look at [ResetPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.resetpassword.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation for `MembershipUser.GetPassword ()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx96zecz.aspx) says it all:

> If EnablePasswordRetrieval is false, the membership provider will return an exception. If the provider supports passwords with a PasswordFormat of Hashed, **you will be unable to retrieve the password for the membership user and should consider making use of the ResetPassword method when a user has forgotten his or her password.**

I cannot think of any other way you would want to *read* the password .